# .NET Core React Project Doesn't See NPM modules

Tags: visual-studio-2017, react-redux, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying a React/Redux .NET core (2.0) web project in Visual Studio 2017. And I've installed font-awesome using npm. It's there and I can see it in the node_modules folder, but I'm not sure if the web project should see it automatically or if I have to drag it into my dist folder and edit my layout page to see it. I'm not against doing that, but as a VS programmer, I'm used to things being a bit more automatic mainly for the sake of package updates. I'm not really confortable editting the vendor.js or vendor-manifest.json files.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? (no guesses, please.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for an answer to a similar question and came across FA's package specifically for React. They have some good instructions on [this page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/react-fontawesome).

Comment: I went digging around and found the same thing on the [Font-Awesome site](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/js-component-packages). I didn't want to use just any old package, but if FA says to use that one, then that's okay for me.

Comment: Learned about this one as well: [react-icons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-icons). Learned about it from [Eve Porcello](https://www.lynda.com/Eve-Porcello/1874244-1.html)'s react course on [Lynda.com](https://www.lynda.com/React-js-tutorials/Incorporating-router/496905/573051-4.html).